# how to move the image control to specific x y co ordination by using of animation class in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation

Please help me how to move the image as automatically to specific x y position by using of animation class in windows phone 7, i have tried by Point animation class but this is not working for image control but working for object, so please tell me what kind of animation class should i use for moving image in windows phone 7

and my code is

XAML

```
                </PointAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Canvas.Resources>
        <Image  Source="qq.jpg" Width="200" Height="100" x:Name="MyImage" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" />

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

c#

```
        private void canvas1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mypoint = new Point();
            mypoint.X = 10;
            mypoint.Y = 200;

            MyPointAnimation.To = mypoint;
            myStoryboard.Begin();
        }
```

Comment: when you want animations, get to be used with blend. No need to learn about any classes. you can do everything with blend visually. google for tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like that :

```
                <Image x:Name="myImage"
                   Canvas.Left="10"
                   Canvas.Top="10"
                   Width="200"
                   Height="100"
                   Source="/Assets/qq.jpg">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
```

and then in code behind :

```
            TranslateTransform trans = myImage.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            DoubleAnimation anima1 = new DoubleAnimation();
            anima1.To = 150;

            Storyboard.SetTarget(anima1, trans);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima1, new
            PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));
            // Create storyboard, add animation, and fire it up!
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(anima1);
            storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad Emad, i just need all code being as runtime code so please tell me how to convert the above xaml code into c# ?.

Comment: and u have said only x points for moving, so please tell me how to set both x and y points to moving image at a time?.

Comment: you can set Y by the same way you done with x. and about XAML you can do it in code behind like this :             Image img = new Image();
            img.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

Comment: Thank u for ur Reply, Actually i need can i set both x and y points in single line code?.